# Does this groupoid have a quasi-diagonal reduced $C^*$-algebra?

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, groupoids

Let $H$ be a discrete group, and let $X$ be the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{N}$. Consider the étale groupoid $G = H \times \{\infty\} \sqcup \mathbb{N}$, whose unit space is $X$, and with operations:

1. $G$ is a group bundle: $s(g) = r(g)$ for every $g \in G$
2. The isotropy at every $k \in \mathbb{N}$ is trivial: $G_k = \{g \in G \mid s(g) = k\} = \{k\}$
3. The isotropy at $\infty$ is $H$: $G_\infty = \{g \in G \mid s(g) = \infty\} = H$

**Question:** Can $C_r^*(G)$ be quasi-diagonal, and $H$ be non-amenable?

Note that (modulo the Tikuisis-White-Winter theorem) it is not hard to prove that if $H$ is amenable then $C_r^*(G)$ is quasi-diagonal. Moreover, a non-amenable fiber can only happen in a non-isolated point of $X$.

**Recall:** We say that a separable $C^*$-algebra $A$ is *quasi-diagonal* if there are contractive and completely positive maps $\varphi_n \colon A \rightarrow M_{k(n)}$ such that $\|\varphi_n(a)\| \rightarrow \|a\|$ and $\|\varphi_n(ab) - \varphi_n(a)\varphi_n(b)\| \rightarrow 0$ for every $a, b \in A$.

Comment: What topology are you giving?  Are you giving the non-Hausdorff topology that any neighborhood of $(g,\infty)$ contains all but finitely many $k\in \mathbb N$?

Comment: This is essentially an inverse semigroup $C^*$-algebra  but I don't know if it helps.  You can take the inverse monoid $M$ with group of units $H$, a zero and a countably infinite set of orthogonal idempotents which are stabilized by the elements of $H$ on either side and this will be Paterson's universal groupoid.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg thanks, I knew this already. This is actually the point of view I come from, though I thought people who knew about quasi-diagonality would know more about groupoids than inverse semigroups. And yes, the topology I'm equipping it with is non Hausdorff, and every neighborhood of $(g, \infty)$ contains cofinitely many $k$.

Comment: What about Thompson's simple group V for your H.  It's nonamenable and since it has no finite dimensional representations that are non-trivial maybe your maps phi_n will be hard to find

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Hm... maybe? I mean, that's not what I want. I want the maps $\varphi_n$ to exist. Maybe I should point out for other readers that, in this setting, $C_r^*(G)$ is in between $C_{full}^*(H)$ and $C_r^*(H)$, and I'm asking whether that intermediate (or exotic) C*-algebra can be quasi-diagonal.

Comment: @DiegoMartínez Can you describe the unitary representation of $H$ that generates $C^*_r(G)$?

Comment: @CalebEckhardt Actually, I can't, good point! I was thinking that $\pi \colon H \rightarrow \mathcal{B}(\ell^2(H \sqcup \mathbb{N}))$, where $\pi_h \delta_x = \delta_{hx}$ if $x \in H$ and $\pi_h \delta_x = \delta_{x}$ when $x \not\in H$ would generate $C_r^*(G)$, but it doesn't. Incidentally, I would also be interested in whether $C_\pi^*(H)$ is quasi-diagonal, as it's not that different from the original $C_r^*(G)$.

Comment: @DiegoMartínez In that case it will only be QD when $H$ is amenable.  Suppose $H$ is not amenable. Since $\pi$ is the direct sum of the left regular and infinitely many trivial representations and the trivial representation does not weakly contain the left regular it follows that $C^*_\pi(H)\cong C^*_r(H)\oplus \mathbb{C}.$  If $C^*_r(H)\oplus \mathbb{C}$ were QD then $C^*_r(H)$ would also be since it is a subalgebra.  But $C^*_r(H)$ isn't QD since $H$ is not amenable.

Comment: Hm.. That's indeed what I suspected, but I hadn't thought of going that way. Thanks!